# Need to separate particular String from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a output like this

Output :

```
[{service: 'xdc'},{service: 'cddc'}, {service:
'cdcd'},{service: 'cddc'}]
```

I need to convert like this

output : `[xdc,cddc,cdcd,cddc]`

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. SO isn't a code-writing forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combined with [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Code:

```js
const output = [{service: 'xdc'},{service: 'cddc'}, {service: 'cdcd'},{service: 'cddc'}]

const result = output.map(({ service }) => service)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Array.map():

```js
const output=[{service: 'xdc'},{service: 'cddc'}, {service: 'cdcd'},{service: 'cddc'}]
const result = output.map(el => el.service)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `forEach()` loop in this case:

```js
var data = [{service: 'xdc'},{service: 'cddc'}, {service:
'cdcd'},{service: 'cddc'}]

var output = [];

data.forEach(element => {
output.push(element.service);
});

console.log(output);
```